# Can I execute a Linux binary without the execute permission bit being set?

Tags: linux

Is there a way to run an executable binary file under Linux which does not have the execute bit set? `chmod +x` is not an option.

E.g. it's permissions may be `r--r--r--` only.

Executing scripts is possible without setting the execute bit and putting in a shebang by passing the source to the interpreter, e.g. `bash script.sh` or `python script.py`.

So is there something like `execute abinaryfile` that will load the object code into memory and run it?

Comment: make a copy and chmod an option?

Comment: No, I'm wondering if there is a way to execute a binary in an environment where the permission bit can't be set (on the given file or any copies of it...)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use /lib/ld*.so as an ELF interpreter, like so:

```bash
cp /bin/ls /tmp/ls
chmod a-x /tmp/ls
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /tmp/ls
```

The actual name differs from architecture to architecture. Some names include `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and `/lib/ld-2.7.so`. You can probably find it singularly as `/lib/ld*`.

Comment: great info.....anyways what does ld stands for?

Comment: @VineetMenon `ld` is the program linker/loader. It finds and loads the shared libraries used by the program, and then executes it. `ld-linux` handles ELF binaries.

Comment: Ok, what if `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` isn't executable (is that even possible?)

Comment: @ultrasawblade AFAIK, only executable `.so`s can be loaded, and `ld-linux` is kind of important.

Comment: On 64-bit Ubuntu it is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

Answer (score 1):

No.  At least, not in the same way.  You are still executing a binary when you do the python thing.  Python is +x.  You would need to compile something that can load a file and execute it.

TiCL should make his/her response an answer because it is the best way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I understand "python" is a binary in that instance. What I was hoping for is that the "compile something that can load a file and execute it" already existed...

Comment: @Tom You'll find C programs that can read an binary into memory and execute it. I don't know if Python is low level enough to do it in the C way, though.

Answer (score 0):

**The `exec` syscall of the Linux kernel fails with `EACCES` if the file is not executable**

While you can do `sh myprog.sh`, trying to run the program as `./myprog.sh` cannot work, since when you do that:

- Bash uses the exec system call on `./myprog.sh`
- the shebangs are interpreted directly by the `exec` system call of the Linux kernel as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt/40938801#40938801
- the Linux kernel refuses to execute files without executable permission

This can be verified with `main.c`:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char *argv[] = {"myprog", NULL};
    char *envp[] = {NULL};
    int ret;
    ret = execve("myprog.sh", argv, envp);
    perror("execve");
    printf("%d\n", errno);
    printf("%d\n", EACCES);
}
```

and `myprog.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo worked
```

If `myprog.sh` is not executable, `main` fails with:

```
execve: Permission denied
13
13
```

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10, `gcc -std=c99`.

POSIX 7 mentions that at:

> The exec functions, except for fexecve(), shall fail if:
>
> [EACCES]
> Search permission is denied for a directory listed in the new process image file's path prefix, or the new process image file denies execution permission.

Further rationale can be found at: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66550/unix-execute-permission-can-be-easily-bypassed-is-it-superfluous-or-whats-the